# Parallel.For w Action that creates different tasks, c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, parallel-processing

I want to in parallel load a list with tasks, and then in parallel execute those tasks.
The tasks take a method as action, but I need that method to work on different objects for every task. But I couldn't pass in parameters.

So I'm thinking of a solution like this:

```
public static Order order = new Order();
public static Queue<SubOrder> subsQ = order.SubOrders;

public void Work()
{
    Task[] taskList = TaskMaker(order.SubOrders.Count);
    Task.WaitAll(taskList);
}

public Task[] TaskMaker(int orderCount)
{
    Task[] taskList = new Task[order.SubOrders.Count];
    Parallel.For(0, taskList.Length, i => taskList[i] = new Task(ExecuteSubOrder) );
    return taskList;
}

public void ExecuteSubOrder()
{
    SubOrder subO = subsQ.Dequeue();
    // ... execute suborder, some webrequest etc.
    ordersCompletedTable.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(new SubOrder(subO.SubOrderId, subO.Status)),
        new TableRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 3) });
}

public class Order
{
    public Queue<SubOrder> SubOrders { get; set; }
}
```

The method executes an order, and upon every completed order, records that in an azure table.
The method dequeues a new order for every task that I put into a Task[] with Parallel.For, so that I can then call Parallel.WaitAll with that task-array.

Can this be done so, or should I do it differently?
Am I getting the job done in parallel here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Parallel.For` to create a new task for each suborder, but then retrieving the suborders from a shared data structure within the tasks. This is not the ideal route, since it will lead to a race hazard (if unsynchronized) or a bottleneck (if synchronized) when each task starts executing.

Instead, alter the definition of the `ExecuteSubOrder` method to accept its suborder as parameter, then use `Parallel.ForEach` to parallelize the suborders onto tasks. `Parallel.ForEach` also takes care of waiting for all suborders to complete before returning.

```
public void Work()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(order.SubOrders, ExecuteSubOrder);
}

public void ExecuteSubOrder(SubOrder subO)
{
    // ... execute suborder, some webrequest etc.
    ordersCompletedTable.Execute(TableOperation.Insert(new SubOrder(subO.SubOrderId, subO.Status)),
        new TableRequestOptions() { RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 3) });
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! Much better. If I also want to process the Orders in parallel, with a worker role polling an Azure Queue for them (with order = await orderQueue.GetMessageAsync()) and then calling that Work()-method, would that be working well?

Comment: @right_there: I can't really answer that; I don't have much experience with Azure. I'd suggest opening another question for it to get someone else's reply.

Comment: Ok, that's great, thank you man. I'll generalize my question anyway though, if anyone would happen to have an answer: Since there are also a lot of Orders coming in (with their suborders), would it be possible to - in the same way as above - make the execution of Work() parallel for each order (changing Work() to take Order as parameter)? Maybe something like: Parallel.ForEach(List<Order>, Work)..? Would this actually make operations even more parallel, or would it require like 16+ cores (just an example) to notice any difference? Case: let's say 20 orders coming in with 300 suborders in each.

Comment: Yes, nested parallelism is supported (and encouraged) in TPL. The TPL infrastructure will take care of maintaining the optimal number of threads onto which to schedule your tasks, so you'd be fine even on just a 4-core.

Comment: In other words: Even though you'd be generating 6000 tasks, .NET would execute these on a thread pool with a small number of threads (typically a small multiple of the number of cores; e.g. 16 threads on a 4-core machine). Thus, the 6000 tasks wouldn't be really *all* executed in parallel; rather, they would be queued and processed successively by the threads in the thread pool.